# How can I filter the results of 'git fsck --unreachable'

Tags: git

I'm trying to look for unreachable commits that use certain file `somefile.jsx`, say. Can I do that? Or can I look for ones that contain a certain specific in one of the files? The deeper problem I have hundreds of unreachable commits there's one I'm looking for ..

Comment: Why are you looking for this particular commit? Would [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) help?

Comment: @Schwern I'm looking to apply a set of changes I stashed and have since popped. I know it's stored somwhere as a dangling commit, unreachable commit, unreachable blob or something like that. I'm having trouble finding it since I don't the hash that corresponds to it. So I'd like to search by the fact that I know it touched `somefile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Run `git fsck --unreachable --no-progress` to get just the lines with the commit info.
2. Grep it for just commits, `grep 'unreachable commit'`.
3. Pipe it to `cut -d' ' -f3` to get the commit it (the 3rd field).

Putting that all together...

```
git fsck --unreachable --no-progress | grep 'unreachable commit' | cut -d' ' -f3
```

Now you have a list of all the unreachable commits. Put that in a file.

You can run `git --no-pager log --format=oneline -n1 --stat <commit id>` on each of them to see what files they changed. Here's a little Perl one-liner to do that.

```
perl -nwle 'system "git --no-pager log --format=oneline -n1 --stat $_"' <commit file>
```

You can even grep for "WIP" to find old stashes.

Answer (score 0):

See all changes for a certain file with `git log <filename>`.

If you ran `git pop`, then you removed the changes from the stash and moved them to the working tree. Then, if you added and committed more changes, they would have been included in a commit along the way.

If you don't see the changes you're looking for with `git log <filename>`, make sure you run `git status` to see what's in your working directory and staging area.